# How to pronounce 'managed to' and other similar phrases with -id sound followed by 'to'?

Tags: pronunciation, consonant-clusters

I know that when pronouncing phrases like 'attached to' the -ed sound, effectively the 't' sound in this case, combines with the 't' sound of 'to' to become a long 't'. But what about when pronouncing 'managed to' or 'merged to' or other similar phrases that have the -id sound sandwiched between two other consonants and the middle and the last consonants are very similar in sound but not exactly the same? Is there a distinct -id sound followed by the 't' sound of 'to' or is the -ed sound dropped entirely?

Comment: Not everyone pronounces '-ed to' in a merged way. Each consonant (the 'd' and the 't') can be pronounced separately, and careful or clear speakers usually do this.

Comment: In my speech, normally the /d/ disappears, but if I'm speaking carefully, it is there but unreleased and not noticeably voiced, so it becomes a long /t:/. I would have to be speaking extremely carefully for a distinct released /d/ bfore the /t/.